# Fire (dispatch) custom event with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, testing-library

Is there a way to fire a custom event with react-testing-library? I couldn't find such example in their docs.

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.body.addEventListener('customEvent', onEvent);
}, []);
```

I want to fire custom event (sth. like `fireEvent('customEvent')` and test if `onEvent` was called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [fireEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/#fireevent) to dispatch a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#adding_custom_data_%E2%80%93_customevent) on `document.body` HTML element. I added spy to `console.log()` method to check if the `onEvent` event handler is called or not.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener('customEvent', onEvent);
  }, []);

  function onEvent(e) {
    console.log(e.detail);
  }

  return <div>app</div>;
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { App } from './';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';

describe('67416971', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    render(<App />);
    fireEvent(document.body, new CustomEvent('customEvent', { detail: 'teresa teng' }));
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('teresa teng');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67416971/index.test.tsx (8.781 s)
  67416971
    ✓ should pass (35 ms)

  console.log
    teresa teng

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.638 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
"react": "^16.14.0"
```